# XPages Style Class does not work on Label in browser but appears in Designer

Tags: xpages

This has been eating at me for a while now.  I seem to run into the issue sometimes -- I have a label that has a style class from a stylesheet that I can see working correctly in Domino Designer:
[image: Style class shows in Domino Designer]

However, when it appears on the web, there in no styling:
[image: Style class does not appear on web]

I have performed a Clean which I thought might correct this issue.

Here is the code:

```
<xp:label value="Email Address is already in use." id="emailExistsText"
styleClass="myCustomErrorMessage">
<xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:var emailCheck = sessionScope.get("emailExists");
    if (emailCheck == "true") { 
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }}]]>
</xp:this.rendered>
```

Is it because there is a hide/when script on the label?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you creating your own error message instead using the default error message functionality? You still can change the CSS style of the error message.

Comment: I am using my own error message because the Display Error control seems to only work with a required message from the field it is associated with.  That message is appearing based on a sessionScope value I am setting.  I could not find any samples to have that message appear in the Display Error Control.  If there is something out there, could you point me to it?  Thanks!

Comment: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/bpmpblog.nsf/dx/better-ssjs-validation-for-xpages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed this -- having the style class appear correctly -- was clicking the "refresh" icon/button in the address bar of Firefox.  That was really interesting that it corrected the issue.

After performing a Clean, removing all cached files, restarting the machine, it was clicking the refresh button that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Some other CSS class must be overriding your custom CSS class. Check with for instance Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug what CSS classes and properties affect the style on your label.

Using Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug is essential in "debugging" styling issues.

Comment: There was no class name overriding my class name.  I tried changing the style class name to "thisIsMyCustomStyleClassThatSeemsNotToWork" just for the heck of it and it still does not want to work on the browser.  Any other ideas would be great -- appreciate the help!

Comment: Other CSS classes can determine the look of your label (based on "inheritance"). With Chrome Developer Tools you can see what other CSS classes have an impact on the look of your label. You can then pinpoint the cause of the style (and act accordingly in your custom class).